# UIWebView vs Home Screen vs Mobile Safari Apps

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview

I noticed the Home Full Screen Apps behaves worser than Mobile Safari. I'm wondering also if there are any differences in UIWebView from Mobile Safari also. I'm currently testing on iOS6. If anyone has anything else they want to mention about the pros and cons of each I would appreciate it.